# Chatfuel Show "Buy" button (via Stripe) using the JSON API block - FB Messenger

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-messenger, chatfuel

I'm trying to build a Facebook Messenger bot using the Chatfuel platform but I came to a halt. I can't find anything about displaying the "Buy" button via the JSON API block. I'm trying to use the Stripe version, not the native FB Messenger purchase feature as the users will be outside of US. Now the button works fine when adding it using the Chatfuel's UI but I can't figure out how to show the Buy button via JSON API.

How should the JSON template look like? What tags do I need? I've been trying to use the examples from the official FB Messenger docs but nothing works, I end up getting the `An error in JSON plugin has occurred / Unable to parse JSON message`.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction on how the JSON template should look like in order to display a buy button?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to achieve this at the moment. I've got this answer in the Chatfuel FB support group:

"Unfortunately not possible. You'll have to use a Chatfuel redirect to a buy block or use a webview or create a normal *buy* button with a link to your checkout process behind it."

Comment: If I understand this answer correctly, does this mean you cannot respond with the JSON API to do: show “text”, show “block”, show more “text”?  Do you always have to “go to block”?